# Azure DevOps Connect to Azure SQL Connection String error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a solution with Azure DevOps. I need to create a connection to an Azure SQL Database using an Azure Powershell Task in a Release/Pipeline.
On my machine I was able to achieve this using the following

```
function new-connection($ServerIsntance, $DatabaseName)
{
    $obj = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $obj.Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $obj.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$($ServerInstance),1433;Initial Catalog=$($DatabaseName);Persist Security Info=False;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password"
    $obj.Connection.Open()
    .....
}
```

However when I use this code in Azure DevOps I get the following exception: `##[error]Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Keyword not supported: 'authentication'."`

The database that I am trying to use is an AzureSQL one, so I can not use `Integrated Security = true` as it is not supported. Do you have an idea of how should I face this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test with the same script, it seems that the cause of this issue is **agent type**.

When I use the **Windows agent**(e.g. vs2017-win2016), the script could work as expected.

But when I test with **Linux agent** (e.g. ubuntu 16.04), I could get the same issue.

[image]

So you could check the agent type (windows or linux).

You could try to use the **Windows Microsoft-hosted agent** (e.g. vs2017-win2016 , windows-2019) .

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

Does your code include spaces between `Active Directory Password`? If so try removing them since the doc does not have any spaces included.

Comment: Same exception. ##[error]Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Keyword not supported: 'authentication'." Seems that the authentication in the connection string is not supported on Azure PowerShell in Azure DevOps.

Comment: @delucaezequiel I have not attempted what you are trying to do before but I was just googling around to see if I could help any further. Can you try to add your UID and PWD similar to this template and see if you can connect? https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/azure-ad-identity-specifying-username-and-password/